# Using regex File Search, how to search across new lines?

Tags: eclipse

I would like my File Search to find occurrences of `insert name`, regardless of interceding characters or new lines. I would like to find both:

`insert into name`

`insert into
    name`

`insert.*name` - works for the first occurrence but not the second

`(?s)insert.*name` - fails to find either line

`insert((.|\n)*)name` - gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`:

```
insert[\s\S]*name
```

or not greedy (if in `insert name - insert name` there should be two matches instead of one match of the whole sentence):

```
insert[\s\S]*?name
```